# Direct proof that sum of random variables is a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

I'm working my way through some exercises and I came across one that I'm having a difficult time with.

Assume the probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbb{P})$.

I'll use the standard shorthand $\{ Z < a\} \equiv \{ \omega \in \Omega: Z(\omega) < a \}$

**Question:** Prove that $Z=X+Y$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-valued random variable if $X$ and $Y$ are $\mathbb{R}$-valued random variables.

I have seen the following solution but I'm having a hard time understanding one of the steps.

To show that $Z$ is a r.v. I need to show that

\begin{equation}
\{Z(\omega) < r\} \in \mathscr{F} \hspace{10pt} \forall r \in \mathbb{R}.
\end{equation}

So the proof goes like this.

\begin{align}
\{Z < r\} &= \{X+Y < r\} & \\
             &= \bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}}{\{X < q\} \cap \{ Y < r-q\}} & \hspace{10pt} \text{(confused here)}\\
\end{align}

From here we easily see that $\{ Z < r \} \in \mathscr{F}$ from the properties of $\sigma$-fields.

But the indicated step above is a mystery to me.

I think I was able to prove the following

\begin{equation}
x + y < r \iff \exists q \in \mathbb{Q} : x < q \text{ and } y < r - q
\end{equation}

But I don't understand how this leads to the union over all rationals in the derivation above. Could somebody please help me understand?

Edit: I changed my definition from $\leq$ to the $<$ because I believe the proof would have an additional convergence step which unnecessarily complicates the question.

Comment: It's a good thing you changed your definition from $\le$ to $<$ because the assertion with $\le$ is false! If $x+y\le r$ there may not be *any* rational $q$ for which $x\le q\le r-y$. For example, take $r=0$ and $x=-y=\sqrt 2$.

Comment: hah, you noticed. That's why I changed it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You proved 
$$x + y < r \iff \exists q \in \mathbb{Q} : x < q \text{ and } y < r - q.$$

Now, by definition, $\{ X + Y < r \} = \{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) + Y(\omega) < r \} = :A$.

By your result, $\omega \in A$ iff for some $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ we have $X(\omega) < q$ and $Y(\omega) < r-q$.

We can enumerate the rationals. So either $\omega \in \{X(\omega) < q_1 \} \cap \{Y(\omega) < r-q_1 \}$ or $\omega \in \{X(\omega) < q_2 \} \cap \{Y(\omega) < r-q_2 \}$ or ...

Now just replace the "or" with $\cup$.

Comment: Thank you @aduh, it's very clear when you state it like that.

Comment: @aduh Please check your inequalities ($<$ vs $\le$). See my comment to the OP

Comment: @grand_chat Edited, thanks.