# Proof of the sum of two random variables is a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, proof-explanation

Let's say we want to prove that $X+Y$ is a random variable. A standard approach is to write $\{X+Y\leq z\}$ as countable unions of measurable sets:
$$\{X+Y\leq z\}=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{r \in \mathbb{Q}} (\{X\leq r\}\cap\{Y\leq z-r+n^{-1}\})$$

I have two problems about this equation. First, why do we need the $n^{-1}$ term and taking the intersection? I can understand intuitively if the equation is just
$$\{X+Y\leq z\}=\bigcup_{r \in \mathbb{Q}} (\{X\leq r\}\cap\{Y\leq z-r\}),$$
how do I think about it more rigorously? I always find it tricky to think of the intersections of sets as limits and supremum and limsup and stuff, what course do I need to take to learn those? Any textbook recommendations would be appreciated.

Second question, why is taking the union over rational numbers enough? We don't need to consider cases where $r$ is irrational?

Comment: $\{X+Y\leq z\}\supsetneq\bigcup_{r \in \mathbb{Q}} (\{X\leq r\}\cap\{Y\leq z-r\}).$
  We need $n^{-1}$ (and intersection over $n$) to include the case $X+Y=z$ and $X\notin\Bbb Q.$

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1945998

Comment: To Anne's comment, I'll add that if you are confused then you can do it in two steps. That is first show that $\{X+Y<z\}$ is measurable by considering $\bigcup_{r\in\Bbb{Q}}\{X<r\}\cap\{Y<z-r\}$ for each $z$ . And then see that $\{X+Y\leq z\}=\bigcap_{n}\{X+Y<z+\frac{1}{n}\}$.

Comment: As for your second question: indexing only by countable sets is mandatory in such proofs, and it is precisely this $n^{-1}$ trick which allowed to consider only rationals. It is a good (and not very difficult) exercise *for you* to prove the equality you quoted.

Comment: The course(s) you need to take to understand these rigorously(and also build a solid intuition) is that of real analysis and measure theory. Good textbooks are that of Apostol/Rudin for real analysis and Stein Shakarchi/Royden/Bogachev for measure theory.

Answer (score 2):

Let us prove first that the function $Z:(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\textbf{P})\to(\textbf{R}^{2},\mathcal{B}(\textbf{R}^{2}))$ such that $Z(\omega) = (X(\omega), Y(\omega))$ is measurable.

In order to do so, notice that the mappings $X:(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\textbf{P})\to(\textbf{R},\mathcal{B}(\textbf{R}))$ and $Y:(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\textbf{P})\to(\textbf{R},\mathcal{B}(\textbf{R}))$ are measurable functions since they are random variables.

Once $\{(-\infty,a)\times(-\infty,b) : a,b\in\textbf{R}\}$ generates $\mathcal{B}(\textbf{R}^{2})$, we can restrict our attention to it.

More precisely, one has that the following result holds:
\begin{align*}
Z^{-1}((-\infty,a)\times(-\infty,b)) & = \{\omega\in\Omega \mid (X(\omega),Y(\omega))\in(-\infty,a)\times(-\infty,b)\}\\\\
& = \{\omega\in\Omega \mid (X(\omega) < a)\wedge(Y(\omega) < b)\}\\\\
& = \{\omega\in\Omega \mid X(\omega) < a\}\cap\{\omega\in\Omega \mid Y(\omega) < b\}\\\\
& = X^{-1}((-\infty,a))\cap Y^{-1}((-\infty,b)) \in \mathcal{F}.
\end{align*}
whence we conclude that $Z$ is measurable.

Given that the addition function is continuous (hence measurable), it can be claimed that the composition is measurable as well, and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!